# Arrow changed position when hover the button

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/15/

Notice the right arrow changed its position to the left when hovered. The arrow need to stay where it is on the right. I tried to use the position, margin and none of them worked.

Also when hovered the button should be in #4d4d4d (gray).

HTML

```
<div class="fluid FindHome-div">
<h1><a href="http://www.ntreisinnovia.net/ntr/idx/index.php?key=b74b4ef49443e4ac6699324016bbaec5" class="FindHome" target="_blank">Find your home</a>     </h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.FindHome {background-color:#09F; width:300px; border:1px solid #09F; padding:10px 40px 10px 15px; border-radius:5px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background: #09F url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat; background-position:320px center; margin-bottom:35px; overflow: hidden; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;}
.FindHome:hover {background:#4d4d4d; border:1px solid #4d4d4d; background: #09F url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat;}
.FindHome-div {display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `background position` properties also for `hover` class

```
.FindHome:hover {
    border:1px solid #4d4d4d; 
    background:#4d4d4d url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat 320px center    
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/23/)**

---

Infact you dont have to add the bg image url again in hover class. You are trying to change only border so add only that.

```
.FindHome:hover { border:1px solid #4d4d4d;}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/22/)**

Comment: @Sowmya Why have you used `background` property twice?

Comment: @abir_maiti That was in his original class. I didn't observe that. Updated the answer again.

Comment: @Sowmya Also you need to use `background-image` url as the OP clearly wants to change `background-color` to `#4d4d4d` on hover.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write `background` property twice. Define in only one. And also define `bacground-position`.

Your css should be like this

```
.FindHome:hover {border:1px solid #4d4d4d; background: #4d4d4d url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat;  background-position:320px center;}
```

Here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/21/